# How to change the stroke opacity of the grid?

Tags: pstricks

I need transparent grids on the top of other graphic objects. I know that the option `strokeopacity` can be used to change the stroke opacity of path. I have made a try as follows, but it cannot work for grid.

Could you tell me how to achieve my goal?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt


\newpsstyle{mygridstyle}{
    strokeopacity=0.5,
    subgriddiv=4,
    gridlabels=5pt,
    gridlabelcolor=red,
    gridfont=Verdana,
    gridcolor=magenta!50,
    subgridcolor=gray!50,
    gridwidth=2pt,
    subgridwidth=1pt,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
\psset{linewidth=10pt,strokeopacity=0.5}
\psline[linecolor=blue](3,3)
\psline[linecolor=red](3,0)(0,3)
\psgrid[style=mygridstyle]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the version of `pstricks.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/ the value of `strokeopacity` is taken into account. By the way: you can use `showgrid=top`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{
    strokeopacity=0.5,
    subgriddiv=4,
    gridlabels=5pt,
    gridlabelcolor=red,
    gridfont=Verdana,
    gridcolor=magenta!50,
    subgridcolor=gray!50,
    gridwidth=2pt,
    subgridwidth=1pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](3,3)
\psset{linewidth=10pt}%,strokeopacity=0.5}
\psline[linecolor=blue](3,3)
\psline[linecolor=red](3,0)(0,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I'll upload `pstricks.tex` aLso to CTAN today.

[image]